# I have a set of specific images from which I need to recognize the handwritten digits. The problem is that they are very much distorted and noisy

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, ocr

[the image from which we need to recognize the digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSYuK.jpg)

Now, as seen from this image, the digits are sometimes struck out, have pencil ticks and some of them are even circled using pencils/green pens.
Firstly, locating the images were very difficult, so I simply measured the distance between the borders and hardcoded into my program to crop to the specific coordinates. But the problem is, the rectangles are not consistent i.e. not of same length. And another huge obstacle is these are **RECTANGLES** usually 60*28, which indicates that we can't use any models trained on mnist data (since its trained on 28*28).
Nonetheless, I used the sklearn/ other pre-trained computing models that have been trained on MNIST dataset and the accuracy was really bad it was around 20%.

Now, please show me the direction on what to do, my initial thought was to create my own dataset and create a model from scratch. If my thinking is correct, could anyone guide me on how to create custom dataset and how to build models. I have a good grasp on how deep learning works, (I have learnt from DL works from Michael Neilsen's https://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com).

So, I hope someone can help me and guide me in the correct direction..

I have tried tessract designed for OCR detection and other Tensorflow models that were trained, but almost all of them had very unsatisfying results.

Answer (score 0):

I think a place to start is to consider making a training set, where each sample in the set is a crop that you have labelled. When you have a training set, you can train a model that learns to predict the correct label for an image crop.

There are different ways of creating a training set. You can use ML algorithms to help speed up the labelling process. One approach is to first cluster your original image by colour, and use the clustering to filter out digits from non-digits:

[image]

The pixels above correspond to locations of digits. The locations are good, even though the precise outline is not clear. You can then cluster this image in such a way that it groups related pixels together:

[image]

We can average the coordinates within each coloured cluster to get the approximate centre of each cluster. With that information, you can take crops from the original image where the centre of each crop should now align with a digit location. These are crops of 15 pixels either side of each centre:

[image]

Now comes the manual part...you assign a label to each crop you want to use for training. For example, there are lots of digits that look like a '2' - they should be labelled as 2. You'll end up with a training set where you have crops and their corresponding labels. You'll need more samples though.

This data could be used to train a logistic regression model, which will provide a baseline that you can compare against other classification models.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering my question. I am new to CV, so please excuse me for asking mundane questions. 
So, first I have to find out all the locations of the digits. Can it be done by masking or RGBtoHSV and give particular values for HSV..??

Secondly, could you tell me how to use the KMeans model in this specific context,? How many clusters should I take, and I can't really grasp how can it cluster these numbers? (really sorry for asking such questions, I am very new to this)

Finally, If I segment them, could you suggest a classification model for training apart from Log Reg

Comment: My pleasure. Yes you could try masking it - I think it's a case of experimenting and learning through that process. For KMeans try different `n_clusters`. There are 4 main colours in the image, so setting up 4 clusters sounds like a good starting point. You can cluster pixels as follows: reshape the image into an array shaped n_pixels x 3 (RGB). Run it though a normaliser, and then fit KMeans- it'll cluster 4 main colours. Use the `.predict()` of KMeans to give you the predicted clusters for the input data or any other data. For classification `sklearn` has decision trees & many other models.

Comment: Will try it and will give you an update, Thank you!!